# How do I substract two strings I set up in python?

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am writing my first program. I am using PyCharm. It's a simple conversation with a computer for my python class. I am having trouble getting the code right on the last line to subtract two strings. Please help! The code is as follows:

```
print('Hello World!')
print('My name is Optimus Prime!')
print('What is your name?') # ask for their name
myName = input()
print('Hi, ' + myName + ' lets have some fun!')
print('What is your favorite sport?:') # ask for their favorite sport
favorite_sport = input()
print(favorite_sport + ' is awesome!')
print('Mine is dismantling decepticons. So much fun!')
print('What is your favorite team?') # ask for their favorite team
favorite_team = input()
print('How many players are on a baseball team?') # ask the number of players on a baseball team
number_of_players = input()
print('How many field positions are there in baseball?') # ask the number of field positions in   baseball
field_positions = input()
print('If there are ' + number_of_players + ' players on a team')
print(' and ' + field_positions + ' field positions')
print('then, ' (number_of_players - field_positions) ' are left in the dugout.')
```

How do I make this right?

**Update** Here is the final product. Thanks for the help! Feel free to take it for a test run.

```
print('Hello people of the universe!')

print('My name is Optimus Prime!')

print('What is your name?') # ask for their name
myName = input()
print('Hi ' + myName + ', lets have some fun!')

print('What is your favorite sport?:') # ask for their favorite sport
favorite_sport = input()
print(favorite_sport + ' is an awesome sport!')
print('Mine is dismantling decepticons. So much fun!')

print('What is the name of your favorite team?') # ask for their favorite team's name
favorite_team = input()
print('I found this interesting fact about the ' + favorite_team + '. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0')

print('How many players are on a ' + favorite_sport + ' team?') # ask the number of players on the team
number_of_players = int(input())

print('How many field positions are there in ' + favorite_sport + '?') # ask the number of field positions
field_positions = int(input())

print(f'If there are {number_of_players} players on a {favorite_sport} team')
print(f'and {field_positions} field positions')
print(f'then, {number_of_players - field_positions} players are left not playing and are available for substitution.')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the strings you get from `input()` into integers:

```
print('How many players are on a baseball team?')
number_of_players = int(input())
print('How many field positions are there in baseball?')
field_positions = int(input())
```

Now that `number_of_players` and `field_positions` are `int`s instead of `str`s, you can add and subtract them as numbers, but you can't add them to `str`s!  An easy fix for that is to use f-strings instead of concatenation; anything in `{braces}` will be interpreted as a normal Python expression and then automatically converted to a string:

```
print(f'If there are {number_of_players} players on a team')
print(f'and {field_positions} field positions')
print(f'then, {number_of_players - field_positions} are left in the dugout.')
```

Comment: Thanks @Samwise ! I was able to tweak it a bit and it works now. Feel free to run it and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

When you subtract the values remember to convert it to an integer.

```
(int(number_of_players) - int(field_positions))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
print(f'then, {(int(number_of_players) - int(field_positions))} are left in the dugout.')
```